# Steering Wheel Lost Sensitivity

Tags: honda, civic, steering-wheel, wheel-balance, front-wheel-drive

After driving a 340 mile round-trip I realized that my car didnt feel right driving local this morning. My steering wheel lost some of its sensitivity. It just feels too "loose". I have a 2019 Honda Insight. If I take it to an auto shop will it be an easy fix?

More Details:
The round trip was from Portland, Oregon to Seattle, Washington which consisted of a total of 7 hours of driving (in 1 day) where I was going like 80 mph the whole time. There was nothing in particular that happened during the drives.

When I mean "loose", I meant that it takes  like less effort to turn the wheel but it takes more wheel rotation to actually turn the tire. Before the trip, my tires would move with every little turn of the wheel, but now there is a 1 cm delay from the center when turned in either directions

Comment: What do you mean by loose @LKim? Are you saying you can turn the wheel without it doing anything, or that it seems to take less effort to turn the wheel? Please describe it more, and add details on anything that happened in that round-trip that may be relevant.

Comment: Your 2019 Insight is still under warranty. Take it back to the Honda dealership and have them look at it. This is a steering issue. I suspect I don't need to tell you if something catastrophic happened, you'd no longer have control of your car while driving.